# print function with end parameter does not print anything in PyCharm Python Console

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

When I print i.e.: `print("text")` everything seems to work fine, and I get the output to the console.

However when I add `end=" "` to the print function i.e.:`print("text", end=" ")` , I get no results in the console.

I've experimented little bit using another value for `end` parameter. When I set `\n` it works just fine. Also, specified above anomaly does not happend when it is executed in system terminal (Ubuntu 16.04).

Here's my code:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, cargo, left=None, right=None):
        self.cargo = cargo
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cargo)


def print_tree_postorder(tree):
    if tree is None: return
    print_tree_postorder(tree.left)
    print_tree_postorder(tree.right)
    print(tree.cargo, end=" ")
```

Can anybody tell me why does this happen and help me with this problem? I wonder whether it is a bug or it is just me having this problem.

I am using:

- Python 3.5.2 from my virtualenv.
- PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.3, JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b6 amd64, JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit

Comment: It's possible that PyCharm waits until it sees a newline before it debuffers the output to the console...

Comment: @holdenweb it sounds like a possible cause.. Can you think of any walkaround for this problem?

Comment: Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` calls when you want the output to appear. If PyCharm emulates `stdout` well enough it should trigger the display of any buffered output, but no promises ...

Comment: while `sys.stdout.flush()` will solve this problem, python3's `print()` has that as an optional parameter: `print("text", end=' ', flush=True)`. No need for another line of code here!